# Meteor.js scrollbar position absolute and fade in/fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

How can I make scrollbar to be absolute so that there won't be spaces consumed by the scrollbar? Is there a way in CSS or Javascript/jQuery to do this? Or is there a package in Meteor? Can it also be fade in and out just like in Facebook Notification or OS Lion X? Thanks!